# change the src of an img using getElementBy* in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a header table to sort another content table.

```
<table id="tableHeader">
    <tr>
        <td class="TituloPestana">Col0</td>
        <td class="TituloPestana">Col1</td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(2)">Col2
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="images/pic.jpg"></td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(3)">Col3
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="images/pic.jpg"></td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(4)">Col4
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="images/pic.jpg"></td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(5)">Col5
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="images/pic.jpg"></td>
        <td width="50px" class="TituloPestana"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="contentDiv" style="max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <table id="tableContent">
        <thead>
        (...)
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bodyPass"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the other hand, the JS functions to sort the tableContent and change the sortIcon images:

```
<script>    
function sortTable(n) {
    resertIcons();
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("tableContent");
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";
    while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        for (i = 0; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            if(n != 5){
                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML
                            .toLowerCase()) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML
                            .toLowerCase()) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                var dateA = new Date(x.innerHTML);
                var dateB = new Date(y.innerHTML);
                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (dateA > dateB) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (dateA < dateB) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount++;
        } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
    changeIcon(dir,n);
}
function resertIcons(){
    document.getElementsByName("sortIcon").src="images/pic.jpg";
}
function changeIcon(ord,n){
    table = document.getElementById("tableHeader");
    row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    col = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
    foto = col.getElementsByName("sortIcon");
    if(ord == "asc")
        foto.src="images/orderAsc.jpg";
    else
        foto.src="images/orderDesc.jpg";
}
</script>
```

When I debug in Chrome, this `foto = col.getElementsByName("sortIcon");` throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByName' of undefined.

I need to change the `img` element of the `td` element, but I can't get the element.

Comment: Probably you are getting _col_ null at 
 _col = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[n];_   Create a fiddle when for this so that we can help.

Comment: Most of the time you call `changeIcon(ord,n)` without the second parameter. Therefore `col = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[undefined];` will always be `undefined` and `col.getElementsByName("sortIcon");` will fail. You should check for this case..

Comment: In such situations, please first debug on your own. If you would had logged the document.getElementsByName("sortIcon"), you would have seen that it returns array of elements!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sortTable(n) {
    resertIcons();
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("tableContent");
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";
    while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        for (i = 0; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            if(n != 5){
                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML
                            .toLowerCase()) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML
                            .toLowerCase()) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                var dateA = new Date(x.innerHTML);
                var dateB = new Date(y.innerHTML);
                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (dateA > dateB) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (dateA < dateB) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount++;
        } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
    changeIcon(dir,n);
}
function resertIcons(){
  document.getElementsByName("sortIcon").forEach( function (item) {     item.src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png";
  })
}
function changeIcon(ord,n){
    table = document.getElementById("tableHeader");
    row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    col = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
    foto = col.firstElementChild;
    if(ord == "asc")
        foto.src="http://www.nannygoatsinpanties.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/128x128-facebook.png";
    else
        foto.src="http://iconshow.me/media/images/social/flat-gradient-social-media-icons/png/128/Twitter.png";
}
```

```html
<table id="tableHeader">
    <tr>
        <td class="TituloPestana">Col0</td>
        <td class="TituloPestana">Col1</td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(2)">Col2
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"></td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(3)">Col3
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"></td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(4)">Col4
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"></td>
        <td class="TituloPestana" onclick="sortTable(5)">Col5
                 <img name="sortIcon" width="48" height="48" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"></td>
        <td width="50px" class="TituloPestana"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="contentDiv" style="max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <table id="tableContent">
        <thead>
        (...)
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bodyPass"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

`document.getElementsByName("sortIcon")` returns an array-like HTML collection of item. So in your code you are trying to change source of all collection and not of the stored image. To change source use  `document.getElementsByName("sortIcon")[n]` where `n` is index of targeted image

I'd suggest to rewrite your function resertIcons like this.

```
function resertIcons(n){
    document.getElementsByName("sortIcon")[n].src="images/pic.jpg";
}
```

And pass n as an argument in the sortTable function.

```
function sortTable(n) {
    resertIcons(n);
...
```

Comment: It doesn't return an array of elements. It returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: when I call `resetIcons()` i want to restore all the initial images. Then, `document.getElementsByName("sortIcon").src="...";` is bad?

Comment: It does nothing because getElementsByName returns HTML collection. To refer each image source in the collection you need to use loop. Updated snippet to make resertIcons function work

Comment: @Alberto Comuñas older versions of IE doesn;t support `forEach` method. Use this code instead `function resertIcons()
 { var array = document.getElementsByName("sortIcon")
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
 array[i].src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/oogleg_standard_colr_128dp.png"; 
          }`

Comment: IE doesn't support the "forEach", I allways forget to test the work in IE...
But don't worry, I fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName()` is a member of `document`.
You can use `foto = col.querySelectorAll('[name=sortIcon]');` instead.
Maybe some older browser does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here [getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) is a property of the document object only. As suggested in the documentation it is better to rely on id and classes and use  document.getElementById() or col.getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName("sortIcon").src="images/pic.jpg";
```

This returns you an array of elements. Use a for loop to loop over the elements of that array.

```
var array = document.getElementsByName("sortIcon");

for (var i = array.length; i--;) {
    array[i].src = "new source";
}
```

**Update:** The *s* in `getElementsByName` will say that there many elements can return. This is represented as an array.

**Hint:** You could use next line if will debug your code.

```
console.log(documents.getElementsByName("name"));
```

Then you could see in your console window that there is an array logged.